# Better way to position objects in a Matrix/Grid shape

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I am working on space a invader game and I'm trying to build levels such that in each of them, the aliens are positioned in a different shape.
I have a rectangle shape, circle shape, and a grid-like shape.

I need help to find a better algorithm to position the aliens in the grid shape.

example of the grid shape:

X X X X X X X

X X X X X X X

X X X X X X X

the "algorithm" I made doesn't feel smart enough and I want some guiding.

Here is my code:

```
//3 Line Formation
     private void setMonsterLinesFormation()
     {
         int spaceX = monsters[0].AreaRect.Width + 10;
         int spaceY = monsters[0].AreaRect.Height + 10;

         int newLinePoint = 7;

         monsters[0].Location = new Point(0, 50);
         Point lastMonsterLoc = monsters[0].Location;

         for (int i = 0; i < monsters.Count; i++)
         {
             Monster currentMonster = monsters[i];
             currentMonster.Location = new Point(
                 x: lastMonsterLoc.X + spaceX,
                 y: lastMonsterLoc.Y);

             if (i == newLinePoint)
             {
                 currentMonster.Location = new Point(monsters[0].Location.X, spaceY * 2);
             }

             if (i == newLinePoint * 2)
             {
                 currentMonster.Location = new Point(monsters[0].Location.X, spaceY * 3);
             }

             lastMonsterLoc = currentMonster.Location;
         }
     }
```

how should I improve this code?
(if it helps, I will not use more than 30 aliens at a time, here I am using 21)

Comment: it's a grid actually

Comment: yes! that is a better name of what im looking. (my english...) can you recommed an agloritem to do that? or the name of the subject in the math world, so i can resarch it?

Comment: It's actually kind of cool that you're doing it in one loop instead of two. You can use one `if` instead of two by changing the first one to `if(i != 0 && i % newLinePoint == 0)`. That will let you use 30, or even 100 aliens if you want without adding more `newLinePoint` comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe so?

```
 int dimensionX = monsters[0].AreaRect.Width;
 int dimensionY = monsters[0].AreaRect.Height;
 int monstersPerLine = 7;

 int padding = 10;
 int currentX = 0;
 int currentY = 0;
 int monsterIndex = 0;



 for(Monster monster : monsters) {   
     if(monsterIndex % monstersPerLine == 0) {
          currentX = 0;
          currentY = currentY + dimensionY + padding;
     }
     monster.Location.x = currentX;
     monster.Location.Y = currentY;

     currentX += dimensionX + padding;
    monsterIndex++;
 }
```

Comment: yes! that execly what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to place objects in a grid? If so, just use a double for loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < desiredWidth ; i+= monster.width + paddingX){
    for (int j ... ){
        monster.x = i;
        monster.y = j;
    }
}
```